# how to close other tabs except the selected tab

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to implement TabPane with ContextMenu to close other tabs except the selected tab

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);

        final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.setText("Tab" + i);
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + i));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            tab.setContent(hbox);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem close = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem closeOthers = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem closeAll = new MenuItem();

            close.setText("Close");
            closeOthers.setText("Close Others");
            closeAll.setText("Close All");
            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(close, closeOthers, closeAll);
            tab.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            final ObservableList<Tab> tablist = tabPane.getTabs();

            close.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                }
            });

            closeOthers.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().removeAll();
                }
            });

            closeAll.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().removeAll(tablist);
                }
            });
        }

        // bind to take available space
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But the code is not working. Can you help me to implement this solution.

Is there any better approach to implement this?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Why are you calling `tabPane.getTabs().removeAll();` in the `closeOthers` handler? (That method probably doesn't do what you think, but it certainly doesn't do anything like what you want.)

Comment: This is just small unfinished code example.

Comment: hmm ... why isn't `retainAll(selectedTab)` what you need?

Comment: Test the code and you will see that it's not working.

Comment: _retainAll_ works just fine (replacing your - slightly weird - _removeAll_ in the action closeOthers).

Comment: `retainAll(...)` works just fine for me too.

Comment: Yes. I tested the code with retainAll. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just iterate through all Tab-Objects in the tablist and mark the ones which should be deleted. After the iteration remove the marked Tab-Objects.

```
        closeOthers.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                // ArrayList of Tab-Objects in which we store Tabs which should be deleted..
                ArrayList<Tab> markedTabs = new ArrayList<>();

                // Iterate through all Tabs in tablist
                for (Tab tab : tablist) {
                    // Is the tab the current active tab? if not, add it to the markedTabs-ArrayList
                    if (tab != tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
                        markedTabs.add(tab);
                }

                // Remove them from the tabPane..
                tabPane.getTabs().removeAll(markedTabs);
            }
        });
```

Comment: no .. retainAll does just that: remove every item that's not in the collection. No need to replicate the core functionality of a List

Comment: @PeterPenzov why do you mark such a whacky (== not using core functionality) as solution? It's **WRONG** to re-invent the wheel ..

Comment: @kleopatra you are completly right - didnt think about that one.